# Template code for calling identical C++ APIs from different namespaces

Tags: c++, kubernetes, templates, protoc

Kubernetes has two very similar versions for their CRI API (v1 and v1alpha), defined here:

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/cri-api/blob/release-1.25/pkg/apis/runtime/v1/api.proto
https://github.com/kubernetes/cri-api/blob/release-1.25/pkg/apis/runtime/v1alpha/api.proto
```

These get converted using `protoc` to C++ headers which clients use to make remote API calls. Some Kubernetes clusters support only v1alpha, some only v1 and some both.

The client code looks like this:

```
auto stub = runtime::v1::RuntimeService::NewStub(unixSockPath);
runtime::v1::ListContainersRequest req;
runtime::v1::ListContainersResponse resp;
stub->ListContainers(req, &res);
```

or like this, depending on which version is supported by the server:

```
auto stub = runtime::v1alpha::RuntimeService::NewStub(unixSockPath);
runtime::v1alpha::ListContainersRequest req;
runtime::v1alpha::ListContainersResponse resp;
stub->ListContainers(req, &res);
```

(only the type names have changed.)

So clients have to try with `v1` first and fallback to `v1alpha` if `v1` is not supported.

Is there a way to write a template function that issues the above requests and uses the namespace (`runtime::v1`, `runtime::v1alpha`) as a template parameter ? This would enable writing code like:

```
std::list<std::string> listContainers() {
    try {
        if (g_useV1)
            return __listContainers<runtime::v1>();
    } catch (const not_supported &ex) {
        g_useV1 = false;
    }
    
    return __listContainers<runtime::v1alpha>();
}
```

Or is passing all the used typenames (`RuntimeService::NewStub`, `ListContainerRequest` etc) as template parameters the only option ?

Comment: Personally I would control this at the compiler level.  Create a compile option and then create a conditional alias based on the presence of the compiler option like `#ifdef USE_ALPHA #defined runtime runtime::v1alpha #else #define runtime runtime::v1` and then your code just uses the alias `runtime`

Comment: I have to switch from one API version to another at runtime depending on the server response.

Comment: You might create some wrapper class (to mimic the namespace) with just the alias types.

Comment: it's not DRY but you could write two versions of the function, one for each API, and then use tag dispatch to call the correct overload at run time.

Comment: You could create structs with usings for each of the types you need. A v1 struct and a v1alpha struct, both declaring all necessary types. Unfortunately it will require manually adding using-declarations for each type you need. But this can be improved with macros, and then you can pass these structs as template arguments instead of the namespaces